# get the count of records from two tables in sql

Tags: sql

I had three tables like ORG_DETAILS, DISTRICT_MASTER AND WORKER_DETAILS..

I want the count of number of organizations and related workers count based on district_name. here is the query i am trying......

```
 SELECT dm.DISTRICT_NAME ,
    count(od.Org_ID)as orgcount,
    count(wd.WORKER_ID)as workerscount
    from ORG_DETAILS od 
    left join WORKER_DETAILS wd  on wd.ORG_ID = od.ORG_ID
    left join DISTRICT_MASTER dm on od.DISTRICT_ID = dm.DISTRICT_ID

    GROUP BY dm.DISTRICT_NAME
```

i am getting duplicate values in count like, one extra org count and worker count....

please help me with this...

thank you.....

Comment: This query looks a bit strange grouping by a left-joined attribute. But that's not necessarily wrong. You are doing this, because od.district_id is nullable and you want to count all details per district and also count district-less details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to fix your problem is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT dm.DISTRICT_NAME ,
       count(distinct od.Org_ID)a s orgcount,
       count(distinct wd.WORKER_ID)as workerscount
from ORG_DETAILS od left join
     WORKER_DETAILS wd
     on wd.ORG_ID = od.ORG_ID left join
     DISTRICT_MASTER dm
     on od.DISTRICT_ID = dm.DISTRICT_ID
GROUP BY dm.DISTRICT_NAME;
```

For performance reasons, doing the aggregation along each dimension *before* the join performs better if the counts are high.